# Returning Multiple JSON Records from Single File

Tags: json, t-sql

(JSON newbie) I am being sent a JSON file that looks like this. How do I return all the records contained in a file?

```
declare @json varchar(max) = '
[
    {
        "Transaction": {
            "Agency": {
                "AgencyId": 108200
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Transaction": {
            "Agency": {
                "AgencyId": 108201
            }
       }
    }
]'
```

I'm using SQL Server/T-SQL. I can't figure out how to return both AgencyIds in one query. Currently, I have to use the Key/Index to return the data.

```
Select *
from openjson(@json,'$[0].Transaction')
WITH (
    AgencyId int '$.Agency.AgencyId'
)

AgencyId
---------
108200
```

```
Select *
from openjson(@json,'$[1].Transaction')
WITH (
    AgencyId int '$.Agency.AgencyId'
)

AgencyId
---------
108201
```

How do I return?

```
AgencyId
---------
108200
108201
```

Tried this  (plus others). It didn't work:

```
Select *
from openjson(@json,'$.Transaction')
WITH (
    AgencyId int '$.Agency.AgencyId'
)

(0 rows affected)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your JSON, you can simply use something like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json)
WITH (
    AgencyId int '$.Transaction.Agency.AgencyId'
)
```

The `path` parameter of `OPENJSON` would have been needed if you had something like this:

```
DECLARE @json varchar(max) = '
{
"TransactionList":
    [
        {
        "Transaction":
            {
            "Agency":
                {
                "AgencyId": 108200
                }
            }
        },
        {
        "Transaction":
            {
            "Agency":
                {
                "AgencyId": 108201
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
'

SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json,'$.TransactionList')
WITH (
    AgencyId int '$.Transaction.Agency.AgencyId'
)
```

Comment: Thank you, @RazvanSocal. It appears that in order not to have to use the index, the _PATH_ argument should reference the level outside the braces ("[" & "]") surrounding the data in question. Or, if there isn't a root name, one needs to fully qualify the fields in the _WITH_ clause. _"That's a handy bit of information to have, right there..."_